# Selenium TestNG - Second iteration shows the same assertion failure when a softassert fails in first iteration (second should pass)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have to verify an integer value on a page with different clients using dataproviders. I am using softassert, so that the execution doesn't stop. however, when one softassert fails (intentionally) in first iteration, the subsequent iteration fails (should pass) abruptly and throws the exact same assertion error as was thrown in first iteration. but if first iteration passes, second continues properly. Where could be the issue ?

```java
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod(Method method) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\a0136300\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    config = new Configreader();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
}

@DataProvider(name = "TestMSSData")
public Object [][] getData(){
    Object [][] data=new Object[2][6];

    data[0][0]="url1";
    data[0][1]="client1";
    data[0][2]="Retail Eligibles : 2018";
    data[0][3]="E1";
    data[0][4]="Maria_Fake";
    data[0][5]=7937;
    data[1][0]="url2";
    data[1][1]="client2";
    data[1][2]="ACTIVE- FAC : 2018";
    data[1][3]="E2";
    data[1][4]="Tad_Fake";
    data[1][5]=4761;
    return data; 
}

@Test(dataProvider = "TestMSSData")
public void Manager_Self_Service(String url, String client, String eliggrp, String empnumber, String firstname, Integer SSN) throws Exception {

    driver.get(url);

    try {
        String headertex = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h3")).getText();
        Assert.assertEquals(headertex, "Log On ");}
    catch (NoSuchElementException e){ 
        throw new AssertionError("Error in loading URL", e); 
    }

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    RIMethods obj3 =new RIMethods(driver, config);
    obj3.Login();

    //Verify last 4 digits of SSN

    String sn = driver.findElement(By.name("eeSsn3")).getAttribute("value");
    int socialsecurity = Integer.parseInt(sn);

    s_assert.assertEquals(socialsecurity, SSN, "SSN last four digits did not match");

    //verify the header for Future benefits 
    if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]")).getText().contains("Future Benefits Summary"))
    System.out.println("Future Benefits summary header is correct");
    else
    System.out.println("header is incorrect");

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    s_assert.assertAll();
}

@AfterMethod
public void cleanUp(){
    driver.quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, its been a full day struggling to get this one and the solution is too simple.

To let it work, I created the softassert object inside the Test method instead of defining at class level, not sure how it affects but its working fine now.